# How to Convert Comma Seperated Column into rows and add counter

Tags: php, mysql, pyrocms

I am having a table with these values

Table : Documents

```
id  |       document
----|-------------
1   |   doc.txt , doc1.txt , doc2.rtf , doc3.docx , doc4.doc
2   |   doc.txt 
3   |   doc.txt , doc1.txt 
4   |   doc.txt , doc1.txt , doc2.rtf 
5   |   doc.txt , doc1.txt , doc2.rtf , doc3.docx , doc4.doc
6   |   doc.txt , doc1.txt , doc2.rtf , doc3.docx 
7   |   doc.txt , doc1.txt , doc2.rtf , doc3.docx , doc4.doc
8   |   doc.txt , doc1.txt , doc2.rtf 
9   |   doc.txt , doc1.txt , doc2.rtf , doc3.docx , doc4.doc
10  |   doc.txt , doc1.txt
```

#### SQL FIDDLE SCHEMA

I need result like this. Where id = 5

```
Counter |   docs
    ----|-----------
    1   |   doc.txt
    2   |   doc1.txt
    3   |   doc2.rtf
    4   |   doc3.docx
    5   |   doc4.doc
```

Where id = 4

```
Counter |   docs
    ----|-----------
    1   |   doc.txt
    2   |   doc1.txt
    3   |   doc2.rtf
```

You see i need to explode comma seperated column and count how many values are there. I dont like this schema but i am working on an existing project and can not change it. I need counter to display in the user interface. So counter is necessary too. How can i do that? Also i can not do it on the php end because i am using pyrocms and i need to display it using pyrocms tage which does not allow me to use php in the views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab5b0/8) , maybe it is that you want. You must use helper table `sequence`

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT S.Id Counter,
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(document, ' , ', S.Id),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(document, ' , ', S.Id - 1)) + 1),
       ' , ', '') docs
FROM documents D, sequence S
WHERE D.id = 3) A
WHERE A.docs <> ''
```

Comment: Sequence table?

Answer (score 2):

using stored procedures you can solve your problem. [here's](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/) an exact **duplicate** of your problem already **solved**

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no easy way to create SQL query there is also no split function available.

What you can do is to create your own function, as described [here](http://www.montrealseocompany.com/2012/04/17/mysql-split-string-into-rows-function/)

You can also process the results directly in php code.