# How To Merge MYSQL Results With PHP For a Pretty Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have data that comes out of mysql like this

```
production_date| production_net| worker_name
------------------------------------------
2013-01-10     | 390           | MMahe
------------------------------------------
2013-01-10     | 400           | RMaloney
------------------------------------------
2013-01-11     | 460           | JBurris
------------------------------------------
2013-01-11     | 210           | MMahe
------------------------------------------
2013-01-14     | 285           | LTaylor
------------------------------------------
```

I would like to display my results like this

```
operator| 2013-01-10| 2013-01-11| 2013-01-14
--------------------------------------------
MMahe   | 390       | 210       |            
--------------------------------------------
RMaloney| 400       |           |            
--------------------------------------------
JBurris |           | 460       |            
--------------------------------------------
LTaylor |           |           | 285       
--------------------------------------------
```

I will be using php.

Any helpful post, thoughts, or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this. This might be helpful.

[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184529/how-to-convert-comma-seperated-column-into-rows-and-add-counter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by MySQL only, take a look at this link http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

For example, modify the example query in that link to be like this:

```
SELECT 
  EmpId,       
  sums.2005, sums.2006, sums.2007,      
FROM (                                  
  SELECT                                
    EmpID,
    SUM(IF(Yr=2005,sales,0)) As '2005',
    SUM(IF(Yr=2006,sales,0)) As '2006',
    SUM(IF(Yr=2007,sales,0)) As '2007'
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY EmpID WITH ROLLUP
) AS sums;
```

You will have a result like this in MySQL

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
| EmpId  | 2005     | 2006     | 2007     |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1      | 12000.00 | 18000.00 | 25000.00 |
| 2      | 15000.00 |  6000.00 |     0.00 |
| 3      |     0.00 | 20000.00 | 24000.00 |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
```