# Mysql - count values from comma-separated field

Tags: mysql, count

I have to do some statics from read-only db where value are stored in a weird form

example:
I have 2 rows like

```
ID    text field 
1     1001,1003,1004 
2     1003, 1005
```

I need to be able to count that this is "5".

I don't have write access so don't know how to read and count right away without creation a function or something like that.

Comment: take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184529/how-to-convert-comma-seperated-column-into-rows-and-add-counter). There is a satisfying answer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Clever solution here on SO: [How to count items in comma separated list MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020001/how-to-count-items-in-comma-seperated-list-mysql)

```
LENGTH(textfield) - LENGTH(REPLACE(textfield, ',', '')) + 1
```

**EDIT**

Yes you can select it as an additional column: and correcting with the CHAR_LENGTH from @HamletHakobyan's answer:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  textfield, 
  (CHAR_LENGTH(textfield) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(textfield, ',', '')) + 1) as total 
FROM table
```

Comment: any idea on how put this value as third column in the table above. like "total"? i'm maybe real noob, but don't have time to learn much now((.

Comment: Updated, but originally it sounded like you wanted total of all rows, which would be like @Hamlet's answer

Comment: thank you very much! don't know why i was afraid to put the whole query in select

Comment: yeah, i'm experimenting on what statistic i can get from existing data..so that's came up later

Comment: `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('a,b,c,d,') - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('a,b,c,d,', ',', '')) + 1 AS total`

This will give me *5*, It should be *4*

Comment: Nice answer on this

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(textfield) - LENGTH(REPLACE(textfield, ',', '')) + 1)
  FROM tablename
```

Comment: Nice, assuming that no field has an empty string.

Answer (score 9):

There is a small but significant omission in all answers. All will work only if database character set is `utf8` or so, i.e. where symbol `,` gets one byte. The fact that the `LENGTH` function returns number of **`bytes`** instead of **`chars`**. Right answer is to use `CHAR_LENGTH` which returns number of characters.

```
SELECT
   SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(textfield) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(textfield, ',', '')) + 1) cnt
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
select sum(total) TotalWords
from
(
  select length(`text field`) - length(replace(`text field`, ',', '')) + 1 total
  from yourtable
) x
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4650e/5)

Answer (score 0):

All is wrong and doesn't works for me.
The only one that work is this bellow

```
SELECT (length(`textfield`) - length(replace(`textfield`, ',', '')) + 1) as my
FROM yourtable;
```

This is my fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5a8e1/10

Comment: don't u think, this is wrong of saying "All is wrong !!!".A lot may have change in `6` years. please review your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (LENGTH(column_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_name, ',', '')) + 1) as value_count
  FROM table_name
```

Here `LENGTH(column_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_name, ',', ''))` gives the number of commas in the value of each column. And +1 with this value provides the number of values separated by comma.

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for a solution to return 0 for empty fields.

`IF(LENGTH(column_name) > 0, LENGTH(column_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_name, ',', '')) + 1, 0)`